# Do titles on sale vary as time passes?

Tags: steam

For those who <strike>have been living under a rock for the past few days</strike> haven't been informed, the 2016 Steam Summer Sale started yesterday. There are a few games that I'm really looking at buying, but I don't have the money in my Steam account and I don't know if I'll be able to grab another card until Monday (and no, I do not have another form of payment). Part of me is worried that it will no longer be on sale by that time. Does Valve periodically change which games are on sale and which aren't or are all of the games that are on sale going to stay that way throughout the sale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not anymore. Steam sales used to run shorter, better deals for each day of the sale, called "Daily Deals", as well as 8-hour long "Flash Sales", but they discontinued that after introducing refunds.

If you want to be 100% sure that it's not going to disappear, look at the end date of the sale on the game's page.

[image: Image showing the end date]

Comment: The title you chose to make your point...  has some very famous (or *infamous*) reviews...  just thought you should know.  They are often not safe for work.